# How can I get exactly the same results in OpenCV as with ImageMagick's "convert -fft"?

Tags: opencv

**When I used ImageMagick-Q16, everything was solved. I was completely wrong.**

To analyze images from anime shows., I would like to display the magnitude values obtained by the FFT.; ImageMagick's `convert INPUT -fft OUTPUT`worked well, but is unwieldy on Windows because it requires FFTW.
Therefore, I would like to use OpenCV to get the exact same FFT in Python as ImageMagick. Thank you very much for your help.

```
convert INPUT -set colorspace Gray -separate -average lenagray.png 
convert lenagray.png -fft lenagfft.png
convert lenagfft-0.png -contrast-stretch 0 -evaluate log 10000 RESULT
```

I would like to display an image that looks identical to this code in OpenCV, and when I try it in Lena, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4FIH.png)

Comment: Please search Google before asking on this forum. This is a very common topic. For example see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html

Comment: Yes. I tried that, but the output is different.
I'm looking for a way to generate an output in OpenCV that matches ImageMagick's convert -fft exactly, pixel by pixel.

Comment: You will never get a perfect match since different architectures have different issues with precision. How different are they? Can you show examples for the same image from both systems. I have worked with both and do not find them to be different if running the same processes properly. Perhaps post your code also for both systems. Perhaps you have a mistake.

Comment: I'm on the road so I can't provide images or code, but this article pretty much sums up what I mean...
(There is a misunderstanding about FFT and DFT...)
According to the article, there is a difference between the implementation of the FFT library used by ImageMagick and the DFT implementation in OpenCV, with the latter being more mathematically faithful. I would like to know how it is possible to bridge this difference.
PS: I remembered that GIMC is available not as a GIMP plugin, but as a CLI tool. It doesn't solve my question, but it may solve the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I forgot to link to the article.
https://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/omD/opencv-dft-diferences-between-dft-and-fft-magnitude-results

Comment: What do you want as your final image?  Do you want the magnitude or the spectrum (log of magnitude).  The former will be mostly black. You generally need to take a log of the magnitude.  Or do you want to do some kind of filtering such as low pass or high pass and then return the inverse transform?  If you tell me more about what you need, perhaps I can demonstrate. One has to be careful about normalization and about scaling issues. Also do you need the OpenCV DFT or the Numpy DFT to compare to Imagemagick's FFT.

Comment: ImageMagick uses the FFTW package. The ImageMagick transform tool is called FFT but only for naming convention. FFTW is a C subroutine library for computing the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) in one or more dimensions.

Comment: FFT is an algorithm that performs DFT much faster. I understand about that.

I finally need a spectrum.
If I try the OpenCV page and do various transformations, I get a white image in the end, but what I need is a spectral image with clear boundaries.
What I need is an image of the spectrum with clear boundaries, such as the following site.
https://anibin.blogspot.com/2013/01/1_23.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the difference between Imagemagick's FFT (DFT) and OpenCV's DFT and how to make them equivalent.

In ImageMagick's command:

```
convert lena.png -colorspace gray -fft -delete 1 -evaluate log 10000 lena_fft_spec10000.png
```

The log is base 10. And Colorspace gray is

```
Gray = 0.298839*R+0.586811*G+0.114350*B
```

Furthermore, ImageMagick scales the image gray levels to the range 0 to 1 internally and then normalizes the Fourier transform in the forward direction (by dividing by the total number of pixels, N), so that the center pixel value of the dft is equivalent to the mean gray level of the (spatial domain) input image.

Using the above, I get:

[image]

In OpenCV/Numpy, the np.log is the natural log. So one needs to use np.log10 and make the equivalent normalized log function in the spectrum, which is

```
spectrum = np.log10(10000*mag+1)/np.log10(10000+1)
```

OpenCV's formula for converting grayscale is slightly different.

```
RGB[A] to Gray:Y←0.299⋅R+0.587⋅G+0.114⋅B
```

which is likely different only in rounding precision.

The main issue is that in OpenCV, the normalization by 1/N (N=total pixels) is done in the inverse transform. This means that the center pixel of the magnitude will be the sum of the graylevels of the (spatial domain) input image. To make them equivalent, we needs to divide the input by 255 to get it to the range 0 to 1 and then divide by (256*256 = total number of pixels). So here is that modified code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input as grayscale, convert to float and divide by 255
# opencv fft only works on grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0).astype(np.float32)/255

# convert image to floats and do dft normalizing by 1/N (N=256*256) saving as complex output
dft = cv2.dft(img/(256*256), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# extract magnitude and phase images
mag, phase = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:,:,0], dft_shift[:,:,1])
    
# get spectrum for viewing using normalized base 10 log 
spec = np.log10(10000*mag+1)/np.log10(10000+1)

# convert from float in range 0-1 to uint8 in range 0-255
spec = (255*spec).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_spectrum_opencv3.png", spec)
 
cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("MAG", mag)
cv2.imshow("PHASE", phase)
cv2.imshow("SPECTRUM", spec)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This results in:

[image]

Visually, they look identical. If I use ImageMagick compare to see how close they are, I get:

```
compare -metric rmse lena_fft_spec10000.png lena_dft_spectrum_opencv2.png null:
386.182 (0.00589276)
```

**This says that the rmse difference is 0.59%**

Differences in floating point precision can account for such differences.

Comment: I am very sorry for my incompetence. And thank you very much for offering the perfect solution!

Comment: Note: The ImageMagick I was using in my environment was the 8-bit version, which also affected the results. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get the spectrum (log of mangitude of the dft) of an image in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input as grayscale
# opencv dft only works on grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)

# convert image to floats and do dft saving as complex output
dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# extract magnitude and phase images
mag, phase = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:,:,0], dft_shift[:,:,1])

# get spectrum for viewing only
spec = np.log(mag) / 30

# convert from float in range 0-1 to uint8 in range 0-255
spec = (255*spec).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_spectrum_opencv2.png", spec)
 
cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("MAG", mag)
cv2.imshow("PHASE", phase)
cv2.imshow("SPECTRUM", spec)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting Spectrum Image:

[image]

Here is the spectrum from ImageMagick. Note that the log function is a normalized log. So it will not produce exactly the same result as above. The only difference is in scaling from the log functions.

```
convert lena.png -colorspace gray -fft -delete 1 -evaluate log 20000 lena_fft.png
```

[image]

Or one can get a closer comparison result as:

```
convert lena.png -colorspace gray -fft -delete 1 -evaluate log 20000000 -evaluate divide 2 lena_fft2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I tried to process it on our side using the Lena image you provided, but got different results...
Here is the code I used and the result.
Img Result: https://ibb.co/n72F09z

convert INPUT -set colorspace Gray -separate -average lenagray.png 
convert lenagray.png -fft lenagfft.png
convert lenagfft-0.png -contrast-stretch 0 -evaluate log 10000 RESULT

Comment: What is the issue? It looks similar to my first result above using ImageMagick.   Your first command does not make much sense. You are telling ImageMagick to take a color image and use it as grayscale. You are not converting it to grayscale. Then you separate channels, but then there is only one image to average. What you should have done was either -colorspace gray or simply -separate -average. However, they do not create the same result. (Note that -average is deprecated and is now -evaluate sequence average.  In your last command you do -contrast-stretch which will increase contrast.

Comment: The error in the command around greyscale was caused by referring to vague and outdated information about stack overflow. Thanks for letting me know.
The results obtained by ImageMagick are very clear, unambiguous and easy to understand. That helps a lot in estimating the quality of an image.

Comment: No problem. Do my examples above answer your questions? The main difference is really how the log functions work. Also possibly where the dft is normalized -- in the inverse or in the forward transform.

Comment: Is it enough to replace a variable to write out the raw data in png before taking the log?
Just normalizing it with ImageMagick may be enough.

Comment: In short, it's inadequate. The result doesn't look much different from the program I copied and pasted from my own reference.
I said spectrum, but what I'm looking for is convert -fft, which can be done with raw FFT data. If I let ImageMagick process it, I might get good results...

Comment: The result from `convert image -fft result` is two images. The first is the magnitude and the second is the phase. If you look at the magnitude in either ImageMagick or OpenCV all you will see is black with possibly a bright speck at the very center for the DC component. So I am not sure what you want. ImageMagick will ensure the image is 8-bit (0 to 255).  OpenCV produces a float result in the range 0 to 1 for the magnitude. So you cannot do a simple compare of the two. You could multiply by 255 and then convert to uint8 and get something similar. But you will see nothing without the log.

Comment: For example, if I write out the mag as "mag = (255*mag).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)" to a png, and then use "convert" to get the contrast and log, do you think it will be exactly the same?

Comment: Why don't you just try and report back?  There may differences due to where the DFT is normalized by the total number of pixels (1/N). One may be in the inverse transform and the other in the forward transform. So there could be a scaling issue.

Comment: I'll try it when I get home. Thank you.

Comment: It's just an excuse, but installing and testing Python, OpenCV, and Numpy now on my current Surface is a hassle due to performance limitations.